# Aggregating all SpatialPolygonsDataFrame objects from list into one SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, rbind, r-sp, spdf

Not looking to editing topology, merely aggregating all polygons into one `sp` object of type `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (spdf). There is only one polygon per spdf.

Data ([dropbox link to data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfvrto6x2o4i8i9/data.Rds?dl=0)) (filesize 1.1KB) ( `dput()` not appropriate in this instance):

```
list_of_spdf <- unlist(readRDS("data.Rds"))
```

I get the desired result with:

```
one_spdf <- rbind(list_of_spdf[1][[1]], list_of_spdf[2][[1]], list_of_spdf[3][[1]], makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)

# when plotting can see two polygons (third object is a repeat for sake of testing)
plot(one_spdf)
```

Having hundreds of objects (though only one polygon per spdf), I need to do the `rbind` programatically. So I tried `lapply`

```
list_of_spdf <- lapply(list_of_spdf, rbind, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)
```

Obviously, this returns a list and therefore not what I'm looking for.

So I wrote a function:

```
rbindSPDF <- function(lst) {
# Create empty spdf objects  
pol <-
    SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list()), data = data.frame())
  pols <-
    SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list()), data = data.frame())
# loop for rbind
  for (i in 1:length(lst)) {
    pol[i] <- lst[i][[1]]
    if (length(pols) == 0) {
      pols <- pol[i]
    } else {
      pols <- rbind(pols, pol[i], makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)
    }
  }
  return(pols)
}
```

However, when using `rbindSPDF`:

```
single_spdf <- rbindSPDF(list_of_spdf)
```

I get:

```
Error in as.vector(data) : 
 no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Plus, I'm guessing I probably don't even need to use my own function.

Note: On top of many other packages, I'm using `sp`and `rgdal` for spatial data and would rather avoid using yet another one due to attaching/detaching time and masking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a programmatical version of

```
one_spdf <- rbind(list_of_spdf[1][[1]], 
                  list_of_spdf[2][[1]], 
                  list_of_spdf[3][[1]], 
                  ...
                  makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)
```

for a very long list in `list_of_spdf`, would something like the following work?

```
# generate list containing list_of_spdf[i][[1]]
list.df <- lapply(seq_along(list_of_spdf),
                  function(i){list_of_spdf[i][[1]]})

# apply rbind to the list
one_spdf2 <- do.call("rbind",
                     c(args = list.df, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE))

> all.equal(one_spdf, one_spdf2)
[1] TRUE
```

The results seem equivalent on my machine.

Comment: Thanks @Z.Lin. I guess it could work if I could add, `makeUniqueIDs = TRUE` to the `do.call()`. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Hmm, does `do.call("rbind", args = c(list.df, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE))` work for you?

Comment: Got it, thanks: `one_spdf <- do.call("rbind",
                     c(args = list.df, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE))`